# Setting beamer label from xparse option

Tags: beamer, latex3, xparse, key-value

I want to write a custom environment that handles some layouts that default beamer slides aren't designed to do.

I use `xparse`'s `\NewDocumentEnvironment` to achieve this, but have problems passing down the label.

If I do something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{slide}{ o +b }
{%
    \begin{frame}[environment=slide,\IfValueT{#1}{#1}]
        % not important implementation details

        #2
    \end{frame}
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}[label=slide-label-a]
    test
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

I get `! Package keyval Error: label=slide-label-a undefined.` because the whole option is parsed as a key.

If I do something like this, where I only pass the label's value, it works but generates a lot of empty labels (for every frame where I don't use one):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{slide}{ o +b }
{%
    \begin{frame}[environment=slide,label=\IfValueT{#1}{#1}]
        % not important implementation details

        #2
    \end{frame}
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}[slide-label-a]
    test
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```

The optimal solution would be the first variant, so I can pass arbitrary keyval options to beamer. But if that doesn't work a second option would be to have a good way to set individual options.

Comment: (hiding frames in new environments can result in surprising problems down the line. Depending on what layout changes you are going to make, a new frame option might be the safer approach)

Comment: (If your tex distribution is up-to-date, you don't need to load `\usepackage{xparse}`)

Comment: good to know, that I don't need to load xparse. Yeah, I first tried it with options, but the problem is that beamer inherently assumes the frame title to be at the top of the frame. I want to achieve a look similar to reveal.js where the title is set directly above the content (everything including the title is centered horizontally and vertically). The only way I found to achieve this is to disable the header, wrap frame and insert the title above the given frame content. Do you see another option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the problem by using an empty default value for your optional argument. This way you can always pass it to the frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\NewDocumentEnvironment{slide}{ O{} +b }
{    \begin{frame}[environment=slide,#1]
        % not important implementation details

        #2
    \end{frame}
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}
    test \ref{slide-label-a}
\end{slide}


\begin{slide}[label=slide-label-a]
    test
\end{slide}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!
Just as a follow-up for my understanding: So I assume the macros that check the options actually cause the issue here? Presumably, because they cause grouping?

Answer (score 1):

> Thanks! Just as a follow-up for my understanding: So I assume the macros that check the options actually cause the issue here? Presumably, because they cause grouping?

No, the issue is not grouping, it's just expansion. The key=value parsers don't fully expand each list element and check whether the result is empty, instead they parse the list element, see it's non-blank (meaning it contains something which is not only spaces or empty), and pick it up as an element for further parsing (splitting on equals sign, checking the key is defined, providing the value to the key's callback).

So what happens if you use `label=\IfValueT{#1}{#1}` is that the `label`-callback gets called with the argument `\IfValueT{#1}{#1}`, and what it does with that depends on the code of that callback (for which we don't care for this explanation).

If you instead use `\IfValueT{#1}{#1}` and pass in `label=<stuff>` as `#1`, the effect will be that the list element is non-empty, and considered for further parsing. What happens next depends a bit on the used key=value parser. In the case of `keyval` it'll try to split at an equals sign (it doesn't find any, because the equals sign will be hidden inside the braces), it'll then consider this a key without a value and try to check for the key's callback using the entirety of `\IfValue{#1}{#1}` inside `\csname...\endcsname` (other key=value parsers also use `\detokenize` to prevent key names from further expanding here), which will expand to `#1` being indeed a value, but it's already after splitting on equals sign, so the entirety of `label=<stuff>` will be checked as the key name, which isn't defined, hence the error you were faced with.

---

So technical explanation out of the way, what can you do (except for the nice code provided in @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz's answer), say if you want to only have the `label` as an optional argument (and not arbitrary options to your underlying `frame` environment): You need to either

1. check for the value and branch accordingly, leading to two code paths which will both use `\begin{frame}` (might annoy some editors' syntax highlighting, syntax checking, etc. -- but will be valid code),
2. or you make sure that your keys are expanded *before* `keyval` parses them.

The first of these is rather straight forward:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{slide}{ o +b }
{%
    \IfValueTF{#1}
      {\begin{frame}[environment=slide,label={#1}]}
      {\begin{frame}[environment=slide]}
        % not important implementation details

        #2
    \end{frame}
}{}
```

The second might look a bit bewildering at first, but isn't too complicated either:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{slide}{ o +b }
{%
    \expanded{\noexpand\begin{frame}[environment=slide, \IfValueT{#1}{label={\unexpanded{#1}}}]}
        % not important implementation details

        #2
    \end{frame}
}{}
```

Put together as a small example document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{slide}{ o +b }
{%
    \expanded{\noexpand\begin{frame}[environment=slide, \IfValueT{#1}{label={\unexpanded{#1}}}]}
        % not important implementation details

        #2
    \end{frame}
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{slide}[slide-label-a]
    test
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```